# First Modal works, but second modal doesn't work

Tags: python, html, css

I have a table to display  and in which i'm creating two buttons inside a column and each has its modals to be open.

Button 1 - "Update"; its modal is "modaledit" - doesn't work
Button 2 - "Generic Tech Skills"; its modal is "modalgts" - works  fine

What I don't understand is that, when I Place the "modaledit's" code before "modalgts's" code. It works fine. Can somebody please try to help in this regard?

```
                <thead class="text-center">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Employee ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Experience</th>
                        <th>Manager</th>
                        <th>Team</th>
                        <th>General Action</th>
                        <th>Enter Score</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="myTable" class="text-center">
                   {% for row in employees %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{row.employee_id}}</td>
                        <td>{{row.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{row.experience}}</td>
                        <td>{{row.manager}}</td>
                        <td>{{row.team}}</td>

                        <td>
                            <a href="/update/{{row.employee_id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-warning btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaledit{{row.employee_id}}">Edit</a>

                            <a href="/gts/{{row.employee_id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalgts{{row.employee_id}}">Generic Tech Skills</a>


                        </td>

                        <td>

                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

```
<div id="modalgts{{row.employee_id}}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title text-dark"> Enter Generic Tech Skills Score </h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="{{url_for('gts')}}" method="POST">

               <div class="form-group">


                  <label>Employee ID</label>
                  <input type="Number" class="form-control " name="employee_id" value="{{row.employee_id}}" readonly>


               </div>


               <div class="form-group">


                  <label>Name</label>

                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{row.name}}">






               <div class="form-group">


                  <label>Experience</label>

                  <select type="text" class="form-control"  name="experience" value="{{row.experience}}">
                       <option selected>{{row.experience}}</option>
                      <option>Less than 3 years</option>
                      <option>3 to 6 Years</option>
                      <option>6 to 9 years</option>
                      <option>More than 9 Years</option>

                   </select>


               </div>


                <div class="form-group">


                  <label>Manager</label>

                  <select type="text" class="form-control"  name="manager" value="{{row.manager}}">
                       <option selected>{{row.manager}}</option>
                      <option>Ravindra</option>
                      <option>Subash</option>
                      <option>Subhandh</option>
                      <option>Amulya</option>
                      <option>Dinesh</option>

                   </select>


               </div>


               <div class="form-group">


                  <label>Team</label>


                   <select class="form-control"  name="team" value="{{row.team}}">
                       <option selected>{{row.team}}</option>
                      <option>SAN Engineering</option>
                      <option>Cloud Engineering</option>
                      <option>Hypervisor Systems Engineering</option>
                      <option>Automation Engineering</option>

                   </select>


               </div>


               <div class="form-group">


                  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Update</button>


               </div>


            </form>


         </div>


         <div class="modal-footer">


            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>


         </div>


      </div>


   </div>
</div>





              <!-- Modal Edit Employee-->
<div id="modaledit{{row.employee_id}}" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title text-dark"> Update Employee </h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="{{url_for('update')}}" method="POST">

               <div class="form-group">


                  <label>Employee ID</label>
                  <input type="Number" class="form-control " name="employee_id" value="{{row.employee_id}}" readonly>


               </div>


               <div class="form-group">


                  <label>Name</label>

                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{row.name}}">






               <div class="form-group">


                  <label>Experience</label>

                  <select type="text" class="form-control"  name="experience" value="{{row.experience}}">
                       <option selected>{{row.experience}}</option>
                      <option>Less than 3 years</option>
                      <option>3 to 6 Years</option>
                      <option>6 to 9 years</option>
                      <option>More than 9 Years</option>

                   </select>


               </div>


                <div class="form-group">


                  <label>Manager</label>

                  <select type="text" class="form-control"  name="manager" value="{{row.manager}}">
                       <option selected>{{row.manager}}</option>
                      <option>Ravindra</option>
                      <option>Subash</option>
                      <option>Subhandh</option>
                      <option>Amulya</option>
                      <option>Dinesh</option>

                   </select>


               </div>


               <div class="form-group">


                  <label>Team</label>


                   <select class="form-control"  name="team" value="{{row.team}}">
                       <option selected>{{row.team}}</option>
                      <option>SAN Engineering</option>
                      <option>Cloud Engineering</option>
                      <option>Hypervisor Systems Engineering</option>
                      <option>Automation Engineering</option>

                   </select>


               </div>


               <div class="form-group">


                  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Update</button>


               </div>


            </form>


         </div>


         <div class="modal-footer">


            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>


         </div>


      </div>


   </div>

</div>
                    


        {% endfor %}

            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: Looks like your element nesting is off, you are missing a closing `</div>` to properly close `<div id="modalgts{{row.employee_id}}"`. Due to this mistake, your first modal now _includes_ the code for the second one.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe. That resolved it.